# FluentAssertions - Check equivalency but ignore properties on source only

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

Given 2 different object types with various properties, class X and class Y:

| X (Source) | Y (Destination) |
| --- | --- |
| AA | A |
| B | B |
| C | C |
| D |  |

After mapping I'm trying to compare equivalency of the properties as follows:

- X.B should equal Y.B, else fail
- X.C should equal Y.C, else fail
- X.D should be ignored and not cause any failure, because Y does not
  contain 'D'
- Y.A should cause a failure, because X does not contain
  'A'

Using FluentAssertions I can get something very close to this:

```
Y.Should().BeEquivalentTo(X, options => options.ExcludingMissingMembers());
```

The only problem here is that the last criteria will not be satisfied: Y.A will be ignored (where as we'd need the test to fail here, as the destination has a property which does not exist on the source, and therefore is not being mapped).

Comment: What do mean by "it should fail"? It cannot ever be mapped _to_, can it? So, what would be the condition for it to fail or not fail?

Comment: Correct 'A' would never be mapped to in this case. So the condition would be that since X does not have 'A' (but Y does), it should fail. In other words, fail of the Destination has a property the Source does not.

Comment: Are you using some mapper library for that?

Answer (score 1):

I may not understand all the rules that you want to assert. But you mentioned one thing specifically that:

> Y.A will be ignored (where as we'd need the test to fail here

```
public class X
{
    public string AA { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
}

public class S
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}

[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    X s = new X();
    S d = new S();

    s.Should().BeEquivalentTo(d, options => options.IncludingProperties());
}
```

This test fails with the following error:

```
Expectation has property s.A that the other object does not have.
```

Hope this answered your question or at least got you a bit closer.

You can read more about the used FluentAssertion Api here:
[FluentAssertion docs](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/#including-properties-andor-fields)

There are some more ways in the link to configure the Assertion.